# Identical computers, drastically different graphical behavior

Tags: windows-7, laptop, integrated-graphics

my friend and I bought our laptops at the same time, from the same place, and the same model. Nothing special, just the HP dv6-6c14nr. It was only $450 with an Intel i5-2450m, 4GB RAM, and a 500GB 5,000 RPM HDD. Uses onboard Intel graphics, no dedicated GPU, Win7 Home Basic. Nice little machines for the price back in 2012, in my opinion. Anyway, my computer can run some games pretty well, all things considered: Counter-Strike: Source and GO on medium graphics, Arma2 on very low, Dead Space 2 on ultra. It does the job for a cheap laptop.

My friend, on the other hand, can't do anything graphically intensive at all. *Netflix* causes his computer to overheat to the point of shutting down after ~30 mins of watching something, and he certainly cannot play any games.

I worked in IT for a single summer, so I know a couple more elementary tricks than him; my startup and services are cleaned up (in MSConfig), I have my vram set to 4096. That kind of little stuff. I also added 4GB of RAM. However, at worst, that should only mean my framerate in games is better than his, right?

Can anyone think of a reason his machine overheats so easily? Because there is no dedicated GPU and programs that are CPU intensive but not *graphically* intensive don't shut him down, I feel like it isn't bad thermal paste or ventilation on the CPU. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like the power management might be set to performance, instead of HP recommended.

Comment: "I feel like it isn't bad thermal paste or ventilation on the CPU" Based on what?  Sounds like that's exactly what the problem is (plugged vents, causing overheating).

Comment: Based on the reason given in that same sentence: "_programs that are CPU intensive but not graphically intensive don't shut him down_". Because it's onboard graphics, the CPU being taxed in not-graphical ways (e.g. a few big programs running at once) should also cause overheating, but it does not. Does that make sense? Am I wrong to conclude that?

Comment: are you sure that you don't mean "integrated graphics"? (or maybe those are the same thing) In any case, I believe that the graphics card is a separate chip, in which case the cpu could be making perfect contact with the heatsink, while the gpu has bad thermal paste or something.